# Capture selection from the jquery autocomplete

Tags: jquery, autocomplete, selection, capture

I am very new to jQuery.

I am using the jQuery autocomplete box. Could someone tell me how to capture the selection that a visitor made in one box so that I can use it in the next box.

Example:
I have a form. In the first text box the visitor selects the state to be Texas. I need to know what he selected so that in the next textbox below I am not offering him cities from Florida but only cities from Texas.

Thank you.

Comment: http://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#event-select

Comment: Thank you. I was searching the net and could not find this. Thanks again.